# Django Query Performance: Unidirectional inclusion using ForeignKey vs. Bidirectional using ForeignKey & Related_name

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-key-relationship, django-queryset

All,

Which one do you prefer when it comes to proper design & cleanness as well as query performance?

**Option A:** (bidirectional reference)

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    capital = models.ForeignKey('City',related_name="country_capital", null=True)

class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    capital = models.ForeignKey('City', related_name="state_capital", null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', null=True)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    state = models.ForeignKey('State', null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', null=True)
```

**Option B:** (unidirectional reference)

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', null=True)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    state = models.ForeignKey('State', null=True)
    state_capital = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    country_capital = models.BooleanField(default=False)


Search will be done as:
Get me all cities where name is Waterloo and country is US.
Get me all cities where country is UK.
Get me all states where country is US.
Get me a country where country is US. and capital is Washington DC.
Get me the capital where country is US.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with option B, from my point of view. One is that there's nothing to stop two or more cities from being marked as capital for a particular state or country. You'd need to add extra validation on your forms to ensure that didn't happen.

From the point of querying, I think A is still preferable. For instance, if you wanted to get all cities in the state whose capital is City X, in the first one you would do:

```
cities = City.objects.filter(state__capital__name="City X")
```

and in the second you would have to do this:

```
cities = City.objects.filter(state=City.objects.get(name="City X"))
```

which resolves to a subquery, which is likely to be less efficient.

However, in option A I don't think you necessarily need the FK from City to Country. In your model (*), all cities are in states, so you can always get the country via the state - having the extra FK again means you need more validation to ensure that you can't assign a city to a country that's different from its state's country.

(* although note that this doesn't actually match reality: not all countries have states anyway, and even those that do will often have cities that fall outside all states, like Canberra in Australia)

Comment: I put both state and country in the City() in option A for the same exact reason as some cities do not fall under a state. So state will be NULL. Also, unique_together will be used to ensure that there are no duplicates in any models, which was out of the scope of this question.  So, you are saying that you'll go with option A, right? Thx Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

Option A is better because it contains the same information without requiring a set of fields that will almost always be blank (state_capital and country_capital).

As you note, not every country has states/provinces, so you should have both country and state fields for the City model. In any case, it is a very small amount of redundancy for a huge payoff, and you are unlikely to encounter normalization problems (for example, it's extremely rare that a given state changes its country). Even if every city did have an associated state in your model, it's still better to add the redundant field to speed up the query -- you're then dealing with at most one table join instead of two.

Note that Washington, DC is composed of two places: Washington the city and DC the state. So your query:

> Get me a country where country is US. and capital is Washington DC.

Should read as

```
Country.objects.filter(code__iexact='US', capital__name__iexact='Washington', capital__state__code__iexact='DC')
```

(I'm assuming here that for both the Country and State models you're actually adding a code field to deal with abbreviations)

I would note that some of these queries seem pretty redundant: Why would you need to match countries on both the country name **and** the capital?

Comment: Washington, D.C. is "Washington District of Columbia" which is the capital of the USA.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. Just wanted to point out that in postal addresses at least, Washington is the city and DC is the state. I suppose there's no harm in making the city name "Washington, D.C." and setting the state value to `None`.

Comment: Got it. Yep, leaving the State empty makes sense as it keeps the total number of states at 50.